# Custom Input field not submitting data to backend

Tags: reactjs

Below is the code for my custominput component

```
import React from "react";
import classNames from "classnames";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
// @material-ui/core components
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import Input from "@material-ui/core/Input";
// @material-ui/icons
import Clear from "@material-ui/icons/Clear";
import Check from "@material-ui/icons/Check";
// core components
import customInputStyle from "../../assets/jss/material-dashboard-react/components/customInputStyle.jsx";

function CustomInput({ ...props }) {
  const {
    classes,
    formControlProps,
    labelText,
    id,
    name,
    labelProps,
    inputProps,
    error,
    success
  } = props;

  const labelClasses = classNames({
    [" " + classes.labelRootError]: error,
    [" " + classes.labelRootSuccess]: success && !error
  });
  const underlineClasses = classNames({
    [classes.underlineError]: error,
    [classes.underlineSuccess]: success && !error,
    [classes.underline]: true
  });
  const marginTop = classNames({
    [classes.marginTop]: labelText === undefined
  });
  return (
    <FormControl
      {...formControlProps}
      className={formControlProps.className + " " + classes.formControl}
    >
      {labelText !== undefined ? (
        <InputLabel
          className={classes.labelRoot + labelClasses}
          htmlFor={id}
          {...labelProps}
        >
          {labelText}
        </InputLabel>
      ) : null}
      <Input
        classes={{
          root: marginTop,
          disabled: classes.disabled,
          underline: underlineClasses
        }}
        id={id}
        name={name}
        {...inputProps}
      />
      {error ? (
        <Clear className={classes.feedback + " " + classes.labelRootError} />
      ) : success ? (
        <Check className={classes.feedback + " " + classes.labelRootSuccess} />
      ) : null}
    </FormControl>
  );
}

CustomInput.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  labelText: PropTypes.node,
  labelProps: PropTypes.object,
  id: PropTypes.string,
  name: PropTypes.string,
  inputProps: PropTypes.object,
  formControlProps: PropTypes.object,
  error: PropTypes.bool,
  success: PropTypes.bool
};

export default withStyles(customInputStyle)(CustomInput);
```

Below I am using it on my page.
When I use in the below fashion I am not able to get the value at the back end

```
 <CustomInput
                                labelText="Sale Amount"
                                name="Sale Amount"
                                className={classnames('form-control form-control-lg', {
                                  'is-invalid': errors.saleAmount
                                })}
                                formControlProps={{
                                  fullWidth: true
                                }}
                                onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                                value={this.state.saleAmount}
                              />
```

But if I change to normal input like below I get the value

Changing it to input start sending the value-->

```
<input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Sale Amount"
                className={classnames('form-control form-control-lg', {
                    'is-invalid': errors.saleAmount
                })}
                name="saleAmount"
                onChange={ this.handleInputChange }
                value={ this.state.saleAmount }
                />
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?
I have tried removing some of the attributes in the controls but other than that I am clueless what needs to be done to fix it.
Any help or suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work by adding onchange props in custominput component

```
import React from "react";
import classNames from "classnames";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
// @material-ui/core components
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import Input from "@material-ui/core/Input";
// @material-ui/icons
import Clear from "@material-ui/icons/Clear";
import Check from "@material-ui/icons/Check";
// core components
import customInputStyle from "../../assets/jss/material-dashboard-react/components/customInputStyle.jsx";

function CustomInput({ ...props }) {
  const {
    classes,
    formControlProps,
    labelText,
    id,
    name,
    onChange,
    labelProps,
    inputProps,
    error,
    success
  } = props;

  const labelClasses = classNames({
    [" " + classes.labelRootError]: error,
    [" " + classes.labelRootSuccess]: success && !error
  });
  const underlineClasses = classNames({
    [classes.underlineError]: error,
    [classes.underlineSuccess]: success && !error,
    [classes.underline]: true
  });
  const marginTop = classNames({
    [classes.marginTop]: labelText === undefined
  });
  return (
    <FormControl
      {...formControlProps}
      className={formControlProps.className + " " + classes.formControl}
    >
      {labelText !== undefined ? (
        <InputLabel
          className={classes.labelRoot + labelClasses}
          htmlFor={id}
          {...labelProps}
        >
          {labelText}
        </InputLabel>
      ) : null}
      <Input
        classes={{
          root: marginTop,
          disabled: classes.disabled,
          underline: underlineClasses
        }}
        id={id}
        name={name}
        onChange= {onChange}
        {...inputProps}
      />
      {error ? (
        <Clear className={classes.feedback + " " + classes.labelRootError} />
      ) : success ? (
        <Check className={classes.feedback + " " + classes.labelRootSuccess} />
      ) : null}
    </FormControl>
  );
}

CustomInput.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  labelText: PropTypes.node,
  labelProps: PropTypes.object,
  id: PropTypes.string,
  name: PropTypes.string,
  onchange: PropTypes.func,
  inputProps: PropTypes.object,
  formControlProps: PropTypes.object,
  error: PropTypes.bool,
  success: PropTypes.bool
};

export default withStyles(customInputStyle)(CustomInput);
```